# Android-Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android

I am new to android. I what to know the difference between `Intent` and `BroadcastReceiver`. I am more confused with `BroadcastReceiver` than `Intent`.

Please help me out. Simple code will be helpful.

Comment: **Please see this Link** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app/44881551#44881551

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ok, I will explain it with an example.

Let's suppose I want to create an app to check subway status from it's webpage. I also want a system notification if the subway is not working ok.

I will have:

- An `Activity` to show results.
- A `Service` to check if the subway is working and show a notification if it's not working.
- A `Broadcast Receiver` called `Alarm Receiver` to call the service every 15 minutes.

Let me show you some code:

```
/* AlarmReceiver.java */
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ACTION_REFRESH_SUBWAY_ALARM =
          "com.x.ACTION_REFRESH_SUBWAY_ALARM";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, StatusService.class);
        context.startService(startIntent);
    }
}
```

Explanation:
As you can see you can set an alarm. and when the alarm is received we use an `intent` to start the `service`. Basically the `intent` is a msg which can have actions, an serialized stuff.

```
public class StatusService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mAlarms = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intentToFire = new Intent(AlarmReceiver.ACTION_REFRESH_ALARM);
        mAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentToFire, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int arg1) {
        super.onStart(intent, arg1);
        Log.d(TAG, "SERVICE STARTED");
        setAlarm();
        Log.d(TAG, "Performing update!");
        new SubwayAsyncTask().execute();
        stopSelf();
    }

    private void setAlarm() {
        int alarmType = AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP;
        mAlarms.setInexactRepeating(alarmType, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timeToRefresh(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_DAY, mAlarmIntent);
    }

}
```

Explanation:

The `service` starts and:

- Set the alarm for the next call. (Check the intent it's used. Just a msg)
- Calls an `AsyncTask` which takes care of updating an notifying the `Activity`

It doesn't make sense to paste the `AsyncTask` but when it finished it calls:

```
private void sendSubwayUpdates(LinkedList<Subway> subways) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(NEW_SUBWAYS_STATUS);
      intent.putExtra("subways", subways);

      sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

This creates a new `Intent` with a certain `NEW_SUBWAYS_STATUS` action, put inside the intent the subways and `sendBroadcast`. If someone is interested in getting that info, it will have a receiver.

I hope I made myself clear.

PS: Some days ago someone explained broadcast and intents in a very cool way.
Someone wants to share his beer, so he sends a broadcast
with an intent having action:"FREE_BEER" and with an extra: "A glass of beer".

Answer (score 3):

The API states:

A `BroadcastReceiver` is a base class for code that will receive intents sent by `sendBroadcast()`.

An intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed.

So, a `BroadcastReceiver` is just an Activity that responds to Intents.  You can send your own broadcasts or even the Android Device can send these system wide broadcasts including things like the battery is low, or the device just booted-up.

Comment: I feel that BroadcastReceivers get really confused as part of services. However, I have used them a few times to have simple inter-activity messages, like sending to one in the back stack. No services needed at all to use it. "Hey, there's been a user change. Respond to it!"

Comment: A BroadcastReceiver is not an activity!