# Android EventBus library for print notification/callback

Tags: android, printing, notifications, spooler

Is EventBus suitable for the tasks I am trying to complete? I need a callback whenever any application prints a document.

Comment: As far as I know you will only be notified of the job finish event in onFinish callback: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintDocumentAdapter.html#onFinish() if you're using the PrintDocumentAdapter to print

Comment: I am aware of PrintDocumentAdapter, but it only works inside of the application for the documents I decide to print. I am looking for a system level (device level) notification on print from any application on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is good for getting callback.

But if you only need to use it single time then do not use `EventBus` library for that, you can use [BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3599696/6676466) or our own defined [interface listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3398416/6676466).

Because for using one time the library is not a good idea. If There are many use of callbacks then No-doubt `EventBus` is best.

Answer (score 0):

> I need a callback whenever any application prints a document.

Android does expose this information to apps.

> Is EventBus suitable for the tasks I am trying to complete?

No, insofar as an event bus does not cause Android to provide you with information that it otherwise would not.

Comment: I am not aware of the exposed interface for getting notified when other applications sends something on printer. I am able to control my application, but I would like to get informed whenever printing occurs on system level.

Comment: @DejanMauer: That will require a custom ROM, or possibly a rooted device and some type of Xposed module.