# Get data from bottom navigation activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have two activity first is MainActity(**FirstActivity**) that just show data,
second is BottomNavigationView Activity(**SecondActivitys**).

When I go to Some activity of **SecondActivitys** I want to send data back to FirstActity.

I have use Intent but on MainActivity have only one button that starts some of **SecondActivitys**. That means I have to call **startActivity** without **requestCode** the I cant use onActivityResult on **MainActivity**

how can I solve it? pls, help thx!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, Why you can't use **onActivityResult**?

But here is the alternative:
You can try BroadcastReceiver or EventBus.
Actually EventBus is a library which is using BroadcastReceivers.
You can look there: [Android-Broadcast Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599351/android-broadcast-receiver)

Note: Don't use Broadcast Receivers everywhere please. Because they are reducing the readability of the Code.

Comment: Because on MainActivity I have one button when the user clicked. It goes to one of tab in bottonNavigationView activity the user can change the tab to input data. When I override onActivityResult I don't know what request code to use. Do u have private contact that we can talk? I'm stalled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64456340/sqlite-order-separate-date-and-time-column can u help this?